# Java assertions

Tags: java

OK, I need to put assertions into my Java code, but I can't figure out how to enable assertions in my [NetBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) 6.8 IDE.

Is this the only step I need to complete in order to be able to use assertions?

Just to set this up, I am creating simple Java code:

```
class Main
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      System.out.print("Enter your marital status: ");
      int c = System.in.read();
      switch ((char) c) {
         case 's':
         case 'S': System.out.println("Single"); break;
         case 'm':
         case 'M': System.out.println("Married"); break;
         case 'd':
         case 'D': System.out.println("Divorced"); break;
         default: assert !true : "Invalid Option"; break;
      }
    }
}
```

Then I go to Run* → *Set project configuration* → *Customize...*

I enter in the "VM Options" box:
-enableassertions:javaapplication58

As javaapplication58 is my package

I have used this approach because upon googling a bit, it looks like what you do, but I still can't get my assert to work. Is there a better tutorial?

Comment: assert false is more clear than assert !true

Answer (score 3):

Add an ellipsis to the VM argument.  Instead of:
`-enableassertions:javaapplication58`
use 
`-enableassertions:javaapplication58...`

There's a pretty good overview of Java assertions [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html#enable-disable). It describes enabling/disabling assertions for specific classes within a package, and some other tips and tricks to help you along.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use this with three dots to get everything in the package

```
-enableassertions:javaapplication58...
```

That will also enable assertions in subpackages unless you explicitly disable them.

From the output of `java -h` one gets this help:

```
-ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              enable assertions with specified granularity
```

Comment: The link is broken: *"Page not found"*

Comment: The JDK 1.4.2 docs are gone, so I've pasted just the relevant help output from the java command.